# How to Add a circle and get the coordinates and radius of the circle using one click on the Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to create a circle using one click on the map, also i want to collect the Lat/Lon information of the circle and it's radius. Please suggest me how to do it using JavaScript.

Regards,
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Circles</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
// This example creates circles on the map with fixed radius of 5km

var cityCircle;

function initialize() {
// Create the map.
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 14,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),//can use your center
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {

//lat and lng is available in e object
var latLng = e.latLng;
// Construct the circleOptions
var circleOptions = {
  //optional to modify
 /* strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,*/
  map: map,
  center: latLng,
  radius: 5000 //in meters apporx.
};
// Add the circle for this city to the map.
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, How can we capture the Lat/Lon and Radius.